# How to rebuild the Shopware Administration?

Tags: administration, shopware6

I did some changes to the Shopware 6 backend and want to rebuild the administration to get the changes. How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

Just open your Docker Command Line and execute the following command:

```sh
bin/build-administration.sh
```

Comment: Note for any reviewers -- an immediate self-answer like this is acceptable according to [Etiquette for answering your own question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question). @Real SMTP, feel free to accept your own answer after the [cooldown expires (48 hours)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).